# How to limit an asset issuer to only issue its asset with a co-signer

Tags: assets, multi-sig, issuing, signer

**What would be the best way (if such way exists at all) to limit the ability of an Issuer to issue assets, and only do this when such action is co-signed by another account?**

Also, ideally, such co-sighing may happen only once, meaning, if a particular account already participated in issuing more assets, it cannot co-sign again.

I don't want to put hard limit on the supply of tokens but have it regulated to prevent concerns with flooding.

Answer (score 0):

[You can](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/multisig/). The process is pretty straightforward. Just add a few signers, set account thresholds to enforce the issuing policy you want, and that's it.

You can also define a quite complex time-lock logic if you need to.

Also check [Stellar laboratory](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#txbuilder?network=test), a swiss knife for Stellar devlopers.

Comment: Thank you! That's very encouraging. One caveat: I don't know upfront who those co-signers are. In fact, they might not even exist at the time of when those rules for issuing the tokens are set. I see the process working something like that:

Comment: - there is an approver account or/and conditions that allow a new account to participate in signing of issuing tokens.
- once those conditions are met, and/or the approver approves co-signing, tokens are issued.
- the new account is banned from any more co-signing.
The goal is to grow the pool of tokens based on the number of interested participants but with some boundaries.